# Cordova - set windows phone client version

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

In Cordova (Phonegap) you have some options to set specific app version for iOS and Android, through the config.xml file:

```
<widget id="com.MyApp" 
version="2.0" android-versionCode="2217" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.0.2217">
```

Is there a similar property for windows phone? Even through a plugin.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom build for Windows Phone. That way you can just modify the widget and edit the version number.

http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/custom-build/win/

**EDIT:**

It seems setting the version for Windows Phone is new in apache Cordova 5.4.0.

```
CB-9408 Added support for windows-packageVersion on <widget>
```

https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/04/tools-release.html

[image]

Source of image:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not what I'm looking for. I would like to manage all three platforms from one build.

Comment: My answer is updated. I recently found out you can set the version for Windows Phone when using apache Cordova 5.4.0.